Will crimping ferrules on 2.5mm2 wire make more reliable connection to screw banana plugs?
I have a lot of 4mm banana plugs intended for at most 6mm2 wire that are connected to the wire using a screw connection. I use them with both 6mm2 wire and 2.5mm2 wire. I have found that the screw connection is not perfect: sometimes, a 6mm2 wire disconnects from the banana plug even though I had tightened the screw. Apparently the screw connection automatically loosens when the wire in the banana plug is flexed.
The problem of disconnecting wires seems to be more common with 2.5mm2 wire. It happens very often that a 2.5mm2 wire loosens and disconnects from the screw banana plug after being connected and disconnected for maybe 20-30 times to a lab supply or multimeter. Then I have to install the wire again and tighten the plug. Usually I find that if I have a positive wire and a negative wire, and let's say the positive wire disconnects from the banana plug, that the negative wire screw has loosened too.
If I crimp a proper-sized ferrule on the 2.5mm2 wires (or 6mm2 wires) before tightening the screw, will the screw connection become more secure so that it would stop self-loosening?

The ferrule will surely help, but most important is to provide some strain relief, if the Banana plug doesn't come with a sufficient one

Typically for a good termination with screw terminals, you would use a crimped ferrule, as without it, you run into the problems you are already seeing.
So no doubt about it, using ferrules makes the situation better.
This is the reason why industrial and autiomation installations are in some cases required to have crimped ferrules (either by electrical code or just because customer wants a quality installation).

Most banana plugs have springs on the sides which makes them unsuitable for using a screw to provide clamping can damage to the springs.
The standard for screw or terminal clamps is a ferrule over the wire to provide something to clamp to.
Terminals can still have issues (especially errors with users or assemblers incorrectly installing) so it's best to use a a shrouded connector for critical applications.
